# Annotate one (or more) values in a typescript string literal union as deprecated

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I know it's possible to annotate entire properties as deprecated, but is it possible to annotated one (or more) single values within a string union as deprecated?

For example, given this type declaration:

```
export type BoxProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & {
  /**
   * @deprecated rounded has no effect and will be removed in a future version
   */
  rounded?: boolean;
  variant?:
    | 'neutral'
    | 'grey'
    | 'success'
    | 'warning';
  thickBorder?: boolean;
};
```

...my IDE (VS Code) will warn me that the `rounded` param is deprecated and will show it as visually "crossed out".

But If I try to annotate one single value of the `variant` string literal union type, my IDE will suggest all possible options with no warnings or visual treatments indicating that any string is deprecated:

```
TypeScript
export type BoxProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & {
  /**
   * @deprecated rounded has no effect and will be removed in a future version
   */
  rounded?: boolean;
  variant?:
    | 'neutral'
    /** @deprecated */
    | 'grey'
    | 'success'
    | 'warning';
  thickBorder?: boolean;

// or 

TypeScript
export type BoxProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & {
  /**
   * @deprecated rounded has no effect and will be removed in a future version
   */
  rounded?: boolean;
  variant?:
    | 'neutral'
    | 'grey' /** @deprecated */
    | 'success'
    | 'warning';
  thickBorder?: boolean;
};

// or 

TypeScript
export type BoxProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & {
  /**
   * @deprecated rounded has no effect and will be removed in a future version
   */
  rounded?: boolean;
  variant?:
    | 'neutral'
    | /** @deprecated */ 'grey' 
    | 'success'
    | 'warning';
  thickBorder?: boolean;
};
```

Is this just not possible? Or is there some other syntax that needs to be used to annotate single strings as deprecated? (Or am I missing a VS Code plugin?)

Comment: It is not possible to annotate single values within a string literal union as deprecated in TypeScript. This is because string literals are primitive types in TypeScript and cannot be annotated individually.

Answer (score 1):

`@depecated` support has landed with [TS 4.0 in 2020](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/38523).

It was discussed on [the ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/390) about it, but no at the moment union and insertion type members don't support TSDoc at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with TSDoc in Visual Studio Code. I've tried it in my IDE (Visual Studio Code), with no success.

However, there is a GitHub Issue about the same issue with a function parameter instead. Even though it isn't with union types, it might help a little. Just [**click here**](https://github.com/microsoft/tsdoc/issues/131)!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing and have found some success by creating a higher-level union (not sure the "official name" of this pattern) like so:

This is the entire type for all the non-deprecated props

```
export type BoxProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & {
  /**
   * @deprecated rounded has no effect and will be removed in a future version
   */
  rounded?: boolean;
  variant?:
    | 'neutral'
    | 'success'
    | 'warning';
  thickBorder?: boolean;
};
```

This is the type you would apply to the Box Component by creating a combination of your original type and then a very narrow type of just the value from the nested union that you want to deprecate.

```
type BoxPropsWithBackwardsCompatibility =
  | BoxProps
  | (Omit<BoxProps, 'variant'> & {
      /**
       * @deprecated Use `neutral` instead of `grey`
       */
      intent: 'grey';
    });
```

I probably have my VS Code misconfigured as I'm not seeing an error, but I am seeing the deprecation notice when hovering the prop.